# Как найти все совпадающие строки в html тексте

Tags: golang

Как мне найти все строки `//ark//` в `html` тексте.
Код:

```
package main 

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "regexp"
import "io/ioutil"
import "net/http"
func main() {
    ress(os.Args[1])
}

func ress(url string) {
    req, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("GetFATAL")
    } else {


        defer req.Body.Close()
        b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err")
        } else {
            r, _ := regexp.Compile("p([a-z]+)ch")
            fmt.Println(r.FindString("/attack/"))


            fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
        }

    }

}
```

Только нужно чтоб был четкий результат. И если нашлись данные строки, выполнялось бы какое то действие. Как это грамотно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Читайте же документацию. Там ясно описан метод [`Match`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Match):

```
if r.Match(b) {
    fmt.Println("matches found")
} else {
    fmt.Println("not matches")
}
```

Comment: Как же я вам благодарен! Честно говоря пропускал метод Match искал что-то на подобии FindAll, а все остальное глазком глянул. теперь буду читать по крайней мере полностью документацию.